# How to start activity in another activity in android?

Tags: android, xml, android-activity

Im trying to make a simple card scanning in my activity.
There is a problem that i need to start this scannong activity in another.
There is a place (rectangle field) in the main activity. And i'm trying to start another activity only in that field.

So i don't know how to make two activities work in the same time on the same screen.
That's the problem

Comment: use fragments for this purpose

Comment: Helpful link: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html#fragments_tutorial

Comment: You basically create 2/3 activities with appropriate views, and then place this on screen. The article I posted should hopefully help :)

Comment: You can also use two separate activities and can use the result of the 2nd activity in first by using startActivityForResult

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is to use fragments like @Raghunandan said.

You can just place a fragment in the place you have left.

Here is the link to the official Android site: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html

Here is the link @Swedish Architect gave: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html#fragments_tutorial

This is a really good tutorial on how to use fragments.

Fragments work almost like activities do.

Answer (score 0):

you can't have multiple Activities on screen at once. However, you could refactor your separate activities into Views, then show a single Activity with one persistent View alongside a group of swappable Views (managed by tabs or ViewFlipper).

or

- you can use [Fragment](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html)
- Custom [dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)

  public class CustomDialog extends Dialog {

  ```
  public CustomDialog (Context context) {
      super(context);
      requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
      setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
      getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
  }
  ```

  }

Comment: you **can** have multiple Activities on screen at once - see deprecated ActivityGroup